# fancybox3 navigation arrows always visible with custom links

Tags: fancybox-3

I found some tips, but mostly for Fancybox2 and they don't work with version 3.

I'd like to make **fancybox3** navigation arrows always visible when displaying popup, but without making a gallery. So, for example my HTML would be:

```
<a data-fancybox="" data-caption="photo10" href="myphoto10.png" title="photo 10">
<a data-fancybox="" data-caption="photo20" href="myphoto20.png" title="photo 20">
<a data-fancybox="" data-caption="photo30" href="myphoto30.png" title="photo 30">
```

So they're independent photos, not related by common gallery. Then, after selecting any of above photos I'd like to have links to **prev** and **next**, for instance:

- after clicking **photo10** I see photo10 in popup, but left arrow directs me to **photo9**, and right arrow directs me to **photo11**
- after clicking **photo20** I see photo20 in popup, but left arrow directs me to **photo19**, and right arrow directs me to **photo21**, etc.

It's even more complicated, because all these photo links will come from AJAX requests, but I simplified the example here.

I initialize fancybox with:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    arrows: true
});
```

What I'd like to do is to keep arrows always visible, and define prev and next functions which load new photos basing on some data- attrubutes of img (using ajax).

Thanks,
Mac

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to approach this task differently -

1. Create simple links, not related to fancyBox (e.g., without
   `data-fancybox`) and add custom click event.
2. Then, from within click event, make your ajax request that returns collection of objects.
3. The final step is to open fancyBox programmatically,
       e.g, using `$.fancybox.open([ array of links ], { options });`

Answer (score 0):

Janis, thanks for advice, but it'd be difficult to handle full sequence of links (from photo20 I want to have link to photo21, then to photo22, etc.). And I don't know the number of these links and even the links themselves in advance.

Anyway, in the meantime I found your other example here: https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/zNdWay which inspired me to some further experiments. Now my code does what I expected:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    afterShow: function( instance, current ) {
        if ( current.$content ) {
            arrowLeft = '<button data-fancybox-prev class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--arrow_left1" title="Prev">&lt;</button>';
            arrowRight = '<button data-fancybox-next class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--arrow_right1" title="Next">&gt;</button>';

            current.$content.append(arrowLeft + arrowRight);

            current.$content.on('click.fb-prev touchend.fb-prev', '[data-fancybox-prev]', function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('Go To Prev');
            }).on( 'click.fb-next touchend.fb-next', '[data-fancybox-next]', function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('Go To Next');
            });
        }
    },
});
```

Thanks. Great library!